# angularjs scope being overwritten

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with my scope.
I have this directive:

```
.directive('pkSlider', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            question: '=pkSlider',
            options: '=',
            onSelect: '&'
        },
        controller: 'PKSliderController',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/pk-slider.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            console.log(scope.question);

            // Extend our options
            angular.extend(scope.options, {
                event: {
                    afterChange: function (e, slick, currentSlide) {
                        controller.afterChange(scope.question, currentSlide);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

which is referenced inside another directive using this HTML markup:

```
<section class="piiick-question" ng-repeat="question in step.questions track by $index">
    <div pk-slider="question" options="options" ng-if="options"></div>
</section>
```

(I have stripped out the rest of the HTML to make it easier to read).
The **console.log(scope.question)** shows the correct question when each directive instance loads, but each directive now uses the last **question** that was invoked.
So when I try to do anything it isn't using the question that was passed into the directive.

My question is how can I make sure that each directive uses it's own scope and doesn't interfere with any other?

Comment: Isnt't it a bit weird that your directive `pkSlider` is also used to pass an attribute?

Comment: I don't necessarily think so. You could argue that in this case, it might not make much sense, because `pk-slider` and `question` don't seem to have much relation. But there are plenty of use cases for using the directive to pass an attribute.

Comment: What does _"uses the last question that was invoked"_ mean?

Comment: @zeroflagL I think, It means the last index data.

Comment: Btw: You use the same `options` for all directives, therefore `controller.afterChange` always refers to the "last" question. So if that's what you mean by " last question that was invoked", then that's the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one-time binding in HTML

```
<div pk-slider="::question" options="options" ng-if="options"></div>
```

and also change scope `question` to pkSlider

```
scope: {
  pkSlider: '=',
  options: '=',
  onSelect: '&'
},
```